# How to remove empty lines containing only ends of lines $?

Tags: sed, grep

I have a file:

```
cat -E extracted_numbers.txt 
11.47$
0.32$
$
1.37192$
-4.$
7.$
20.$
13.$
$0.
15000$
15000.$
$
2.87$
$.6
47.$
$00.
0.0000000000000000$
0.0000000000000000$
$
0.0000000000000000$
0.0000000000000000$
$
0.0000000000000000$
0.0000000000000000$
$
0.0000000000000000$
0.0000000000000000$
$
0.0000000000000000$
0.0000000000000000$
$
0.0000000000000000$
0.0000000000000000$
$
0.0000000000000000$
0.0000000000000000$
$
0.$
0.$
0.$
$.
0.$
0.$
$
$0.
279.33$
$
```

How to remove the empty lines or the lines that include only the end of the line? I tried:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' extracted_numbers.txt
```

and

```
grep -v '^$' extracted_numbers.txt
```

Why it does not work? Has anyone an idea what next command I can use? Thank you

Comment: Was the file edited on a Windows-based machine? If so, you may need to run `dos2unix` on the file first to convert it to Unix-style line endings (which differ from windows-style line-endings). Also, please indicate in what way the result of your attemps deviated from the expectation.

Comment: Does it work if you use: `grep -v $'^\r$'`

Comment: The lines that look like `$0.` hint at the Windows-style carriage returns, they likely look like `00.<cr><nl>`, but the CR moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line. `cat -A` would show CRs as `^M`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture lines that contain something (`.` in an RE matches any character):

```
grep . file >file.new
```

If you find this still matches your supposedly blank lines then you probably need to fix up Windows line endings:

```
tr -d '\r' <file | grep . >file.new
```

Or maybe your unwanted blank lines actually contain whitespace (possibly including Windows line endings):

```
grep '[^[:space:]]' <file >file.new
```

If you want an edit-in-place this approach is portable for a file named `file` (if it is a known file name you may be able to omit the occurrences of `--` like in the examples above):

```
grep . <file >"file.$$.tmp" && mv -f -- "file.$$.tmp" "file"
rm -f -- "file.$$.tmp"
```

Comment: Thank you, tr -d '\r' <file | grep . >file.new work, but I have no idea why there are Windows line endings. The file was created on linux Mint.